# Loop merge using Teradata or SAS

Tags: while-loop, sas, teradata, sas-macro, teradatasql

I have a Teradata data tables with more than 60MM IDs for a period of three years. Meaning, the same ID will be repeated in all three years. I am looking for a macro where I can use ID to loop through until the last record with start date and end date being the same.

I have a snippet of SAS code to define the lower and upper ID to use it as a filter

```
 %macro loopmerge(n);

 %do i=1 to &n.
 data _null_;
 call symputx('lower',%eval(&i-1)*25000000
 call symputx('upper',%eval(&i)*25000000

 Proc Sql;
   Connect to teradata (XXXXXXX);
   Create table DataTable as 
   select * from connection to teradata
   (Select ID,VAR1,VAR2
     From MyTable
     where Date between '2021-01-01' and '2023-12-31'
     and (&lower lt ID le &upper)
  );
Quit;

 %mend;
```

This is not working as I expected and throwing an error. Is there a way I can pull this information using `Teradata Macros`?

Comment: Just change `and (&lower lt ID le &upper)` to `and &lower < ID and ID <= &upper`?

Comment: I cannot understand your verbal description of what you are doing.  What is the "looping"?  What do you mean by "until the last record with start date and end date being the same"? Same what?  Are you just looking for the maximum date in some time period? Why would that involve any looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using SAS syntax in your pass thru Teradata code.  I doubt that Teradata will let you use SAS's shortcut syntax for multiple comparisons.
So just expand it.

Convert something like

```
(A op1 B op2 C)
```

in to its components parts.

```
(A op1 B) and (B op2 C)
```

Comment: I didn't understand (A op1 B) and (B op2 C).. Can you explain?

Comment: SAS will let you remove the AND when you want to use the same variable twice in a series of comparisons. So if you want to test whether  `(100 <= id) AND (id < 200)` you can just write `100 <= id < 200`.  Most languages will not understand that shortcut.